# can user copy cookies values from one computer to another

Tags: cookies, browser

I have a question regarding usage of cookies . Say my website saves a cookie into a user's computer after he logged for the first time. and then i will use this cookie to check if the user logged before using this computer. Can that user somehow copy that cookie from one computer to another?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To achieve your goal use [EditThisCookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg) plug-in.